# how to overlay more than one segmented mask image with original image

Tags: python, deep-learning, opencv

I have segmented images and original images. How do I place the original images in the white area of segmented images?

[image: segmented image]

[image: colored image]

[image: orj-segmented image]

The code I wrote according to ksooklall's suggestion is:

```
segmented_imgs=("D:/melanoma/train2/train/mask/1")
original_img=("D:/melanoma/train2/train/org/1")
masks=[]
original_imgs=[]
index=0
for index in range(1476):
   segmented_img=(segmented_imgs+ str(index) +"_mask.jpg"!=0)
   original_img=(original_img+ "/" + str(index) + ".jpg")
   mask = (segmented_img != 0)
   segmented_img[mask] = original_img[mask]

   index +=1
```

I received the error:

> ```
> File "D:/merge orjsegment.py", line 14, in <module>
>     segmented_img=cv2.imread(segmented_img+ str(index) + "_mask.jpg"!=0)
>
> TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
> ```

Comment: Why do you have a deep learning tag? What have you done to attempt to solve this?

Comment: in `segmented_img=cv2.imread(segmented_img+ str(index) +"_mask.jpg"!=0)` the second `segmented_img` should be the img path not the np.array

Comment: I changed the img path to the following error:    
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: what are you doing here? `segmented_img=(segmented_imgs+ str(index) +"_mask.jpg"!=0)` Should it be  `segmented_img = cv2.imread("D:/melanoma/train2/train/mask/" + str(index) + '_mask.jpg')`

Comment: I read the images and trying to overlaying each other.

Comment: I just want to overlay mask and original images.

Comment: I SOLVED my PROBLEM. Thanks 'ksooklall' for everything.                    
import cv2

index=0
for index in range(1476):
    src1 = cv2.imread('D:/melanoma/train2/train/train/1/'+ str(index) + ".jpg")
    src2 = cv2.imread('D:/melanoma/train2/train/tumor/1/'+ str(index) + "_mask.jpg")
    src2 = cv2.resize(src2, src1.shape[1::-1])
    print(src2.shape)# (225, 400, 3)
    print(src2.dtype)# uint8
    dst = cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2)
    cv2.imwrite('D:/melanoma/train2/train/train/1/'+ str(index) + "_result.jpg", dst)
    index=index+1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mask = (segmented_img != 0)
segmented_img[mask] = original_img[mask]
```

Comment: it didn't work. I have 1476 mask and 1476 original images.

Comment: do you get an error? I do see the results, I might have them mixed up the images put this is the logic your looking for.

Comment: can you place that in the question for others to see

Comment: everyone asks this question differently but no answer :(